# Action based on a our home time zone, not the customer's

Tags: javascript, timezone

We sell custom T-shirts from the East Coast of the USA.
If a customer submits an order before Noon EST, we send their T-shirt layout for approval back to them by the end of that day. 
If they order after 12 Noon on a business weekday, the layout will be sent the following business day.
If the order is placed on a weekend, the layout will be sent for approval on Monday.
The text reads:
If you place your order now (local time) you will receive your layout to review by the end of the day (named date based on the above).
**Important to know:** I don't write javascript, I piece together little bits I need here and there like this. I am a monkey who occasionally gets it right.
**Question: Can this code be adjusted so that our promise to deliver a layout to review is always based on Eastern Standard Time and not the customer's local time?**
I suspect the answer lies with DateTimeZone but I have no idea how to render it.
I hope my question is the proper use of this resourceful community.
Thank you.
/Pat
Two scripts threaded within text. The text paragraph follows.
If you place your order now [script for current customer local time] you will receive your layout to review by the end of the day on [script that should be based on Eastern Standard Time 12 Noon].

Here are the scripts:

```
<script>  
  var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes

    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
    }
    document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")  

    var myDate=new Date();
    if ( myDate.getHours() < 12 ) // less than noon
    {
    var daystodeliver = [1,0,0,0,0,0,2][myDate.getDay()]; <!--if ordered by noon numbers in brackets is the number of days until the event per days of the week, the first number is Sunday -->
    }
    else
    {
    var daystodeliver = [1,1,1,1,1,3,2][myDate.getDay()]; <!--orders placed after noon Friday will ship on (3) Monday, if on Saturday, then on (2) Monday -->
    }
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+daystodeliver);
    document.write(['Sunday ','Monday ','Tuesday ','Wednesday ','Thursday ','Friday ','Saturday '][myDate.getDay()]);
    document.write(['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'][myDate.getMonth()]);
    document.write(' ' + myDate.getDate());
```

Comment: I'm afraid you just hit one of the worst things to work with when it comes to Web and Javascript. Try to make your life less painful: http://momentjs.com/ and http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: So I should forget my current approach and learn to use momentjs.com?

Comment: Not exactly that, but if you use the library you'll get there quicker and easier.

Comment: You can calculate the difference between the customers local time, and your time zone. Create a new time object and apply the difference, but !!! you are depending on the local time zone and that person's computer to be correct ... If done on the server using PHP to make the page you can have assuranced the time is correct

Comment: @Wayne Why mention `PHP`? Just by saying that this would be better approached on the server-side would be enough.